# Tips to Learning Code in a Big Project

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Not sure if this is the best place to ask or not but if it gets closed down oh well. I am in computer programming and starting on my first work term. I will be doing 2D game programming for iPhone in objective C. I was just wondering if you had any tips for learning how the code works on a big project. In college I have never worked with something in terms of this scope. I am used to a project with maybe a dozen source files while what I'll be working on has hundreds. It is very overwhelming for me.

Any Tips would be appreciated. Thanks very much

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: First, read the docs. If there is no docs and the project is big, run away fast. Then learn the architecture, don't learn any specifics. Learn only what you need to change/add something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I do it. Opinions and methods may vary. 
Generally speaking, I find the best way to learn about a system is to go through the code while the app is running.

1. Pick a significant place in the UI (the startup screen, some other screen).
2. Find the class for that view. Generally just ask a senior developer. Developers are happy to give a pointer (no pun intended) to someone who wants to learn by himself instead of having to explain everything.
3. Place a breakpoint in that class and run the app in Xcode until you hit your breakpoint.
4. Then start tracing in there to see how things happen.

Repeat the process at different spots in the app and soon you'll get a general idea of how the app works. Then it's a lot easier to catch the details.

If the system is really enormous (like an enterprise app that runs on multiple systems), then a diagram showing all the architecturally significant pieces would probably help. For an iOS app, it's probably not needed.

Good luck...

Comment: +1/2 Such a nice answer for such a misguided question and +1/2 for the pun :)

Comment: I will try doing that. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I am a 3rd year computer engineer who has done four work terms, and I can offer the following :

Some general advice:

- Compartmentalizing your approach is still very useful on a big project, as in a small one. The more specific parts you focus on at a time, the easier it will be to understand them. This is not always practical due to interdependence of programs, but it is still possible to, say, work on the graphics portion alone, or the character's movement algorithm, etc. You should know that in the past that it was possible for an educated person to know the sum of human knowledge, but that is impossible today. Even senior engineers/programmers have specific areas of expertise, and other areas where they are fuzzy. Find what you most enjoy/are talented at, and devote time to that.
- A basic foundation is important. Study the basic ideas of loop structures, classes, methods and the like, and know them like the back of your hand, so when applying them across languages/platforms, all you need to do is refresh yourself on the syntax. The same basic ideas apply across a range of languages.
- Most of all, do not panic. It is your first work term, and you are assigned mentors/supervisors, as well as working with a team. Doing it alone would be difficult, so network well with your teammates/superiors so you can all learn from each other, divide the work, and lessen the stress on yourself!

Good luck! :)

Answer (score 2):

### Short Answer :

Read less, do more, then read when you get stuck. In my opinion, that's the best way to learn any new language and also someone said :

> "We learn by doing, there is no other way".

### Long Answer :

**Rule 1:** Relax.

**Rule 2:** You gotta understand that this is not easy stuff to master. That is why people who do get paid really well. If you had an idea you could bang this stuff out in a couple of weeks with you need to dump that. Plan to spend months working up on it.

**Rule 3:** Understand that the Apple API is HUGE and it is always evolving. There is enough content to learn something new Everyday.

**Rule 4:** The fewer programming languages you've had to learn, the harder it is to learn new ones. You will learn slower than someone else who has learned half dozen languages/APIs already.

**Rule 5:** Don't be afraid to use repetition and brute force. I think the thing that slows novices down is not learning the behaviors and methods of common foundation classes like `NSString`, `NSArray`, `NSDictionary` etc.

**Rule 6:** As a learning exercise, **copy-pasting** might not be the right thing to do. If there's an Apple example of how to do something, rather than copy-pasting I tend to rewrite it manually. I find it sticks better in my mind.

**Rule 7:** Use any resources you like. There are no rules on how you should learn.

**Rule 8:** iPhone is a memory constrained device where network and local storage access is slow. Parts of your application can be unloaded at any time, your application is responsible for maintaining it's memory footprint (not the user), and an event (phone call, memory, etc.) may require the app to respond accordingly and quickly.

**Rule 9:** It isn't about you. It isn't about your code. And it isn't about your code doing this or that. It's first about the user and responding to the user. It's second about your code responding to the framework. You don't usually tell the framework what to do. It asks you for things when it needs something. You sit and wait for it to talk to you. You're not in charge. You don't control the runloop; it controls you. You register to be told when things happen, and you indicate that you're the object who knows something about something (data for a table for instance). And then you let go, and let Cocoa do the rest. It's a very different world. I like it very much.

**Rule 10:** Relax.

Answer (score 0):

When I'm coming to a new Xcode project, I open it up in OmniGraffle Pro. If the project is well organized, you'll see a nice diagram with a summary of the classes, the methods that are present and a little bit of how things relate to each other, important `enum`s to know about, and other helpful information for getting a good overview of the project.

After that, pick a point like @mprivat said and run it in the debugger and get a feel for how things run. I like to set breakpoints with logs of the breakpoint name and hit count (and maybe the value of some variable or parameter if it seems relevant) and automatic continue after a little while to avoid pesky timing issues that can sometimes creep up when the debugger pauses execution. I use breakpoint logging so I don't have to worry about accidentally committing clutter code. (Be careful of pulling new code though because breakpoints don't move with your changing codebase. :))